# Terminal 00 sacred words / witch id riddle,

Tags: riddle, language

I found this website angusnicneven.com, dug through it and found a page witch requires a witch ID and sacred words. The page I found this text on is https://angusnicneven.com/quolle_cencuun_pellsen_en_somet_nac

The text I have found is:

> Essac teiyosess, ent ollrah oyen esseteiya.
> Somet nac, somet nac.
> Aveyas unn, sollesse sollent myuen nyue.

opening the page shows a brief poem pasted from inspect

> Ｏｈ，　Ａｖｅｙａｓ．．．
> Ｔｈｅ　ｔｒａｎｓｃｅｎｄｅｎｔａｌ　ｄｒｅａｍｅｒ．．．
>
> Ｔｈｅ　ｋｅｅｐｅｒ　ｏｆ　ｔｈｅ　Ｇａｔｅ．．．
>
> Ｃｒｅａｔｉｏｎ　ｈａｓ　ｓｅｅｎ　ｆｉｔ　ｔｏ　ｂｌｅｓｓ　ｕｓ　ｗｉｔｈ　ｎｅｖｅｒ－ｅｎｄｉｎｇ　ｇｒｉｅｆ．
>
> Ｓｏ　ｗｅ　ｐｒａｙ，ｉｍｐａｒｔ　ｏｕｒ　ｓｏｕｌｓ　ｗｉｔｈ　ｙｏｕｒ　ｂｌｏｓｓｏｍｉｎｇ　ｓｍｉｌｅ！
>
> Ａｎｄ　ｂａｌａｎｃｅ　ｏｕｒ　ｈｏｌｌｏｗ　ｓｋｕｌｌｓ　ｗｉｔｈ　ｇｌｅａｍｉｎｇ　ｔｅｅｔｈ！
>
> Ｓｏｌ　ｏｎｓｅｔ　ｓｅｃｔｏｌ．

The website contains the words "sol onset sectol" everywhere. From what I know it means "good luck traveler". Opening in inspect also displays another message:

> Sliccush oll.
> Iricent vol.
>
> Sliccush oll.
> Iricent vol.
>
> Sliccush oll.
> Iricent vol.
> Sol onset sectol

I've tried translating it with no success so far. I've used a Caesar cipher and shift cipher but to no result.

Comment: The message ``Sol onset sectol`` seems to be all-important to the riddle. Consider deciphering it first. Also, rot13(Unir lbh pbafvqrerq gung gur jbeqf pbhyq or va n snagnfgvpny ynathntr, fhpu nf Gbyxvra'f Ryivfu)?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question is not answerable based on the information provided in the question. The entire website is an interlocking horror puzzle, and solving it will require more information from the site itself, and not just solving the riddle provided here.